# Text in Chrome during non-headless tests not visible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, testing, google-chrome-headless

I have a newbie question about Selenium and Capybara.

During running non-headless tests with Selenium my test window lacks the text. It is there, but in non-readable state.

My colleague has the same situation with headless tests when saving and opening a page during test.

Should I adjust any settings to make the text on the test page visible?

[image: My browser window]

Comment: you can use explicit wait to load the text content and then proceed further.